# Easy way to do roll up reporting in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, reporting

Is there an easy way to do roll up reporting in Google Analytics when you have multiple domains and each has at least 2 subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware you can't, you'd need to download the relevant data and crunch it manually.

You can follow the instructions here, which walk you through the process of [structuring  a rollup account to generate reports](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/advanced-structure-your-account-with.html):-

> No need to panic. This post aims to offer an approach to help you plan
>   your Google Analytics accounts setup in a structured fashion to help
>   with clarity. I hope that by following the approach and the technical
>   steps, you will be able to collect and manage all your data, make more
>   sense of it, and most importantly, ensure what you are reporting on,
>   trending, dashboarding and analyzing is based on accurate data.

Some further reading is available in [google groups](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/JesBd6b4NJ8)